# compress with pyminizip and return to response

Tags: python, django, zip

I am trying to compress data with pyminizip and return the data as response in a Django project as follows

```
def get_csv_file(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="member.zip"'
    users = User.objects.all()
    file_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'member.csv')
    f = open(file_path, 'w')
    file_writer = csv.writer(f, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for user in users:
        file_writer.writerow([user.username, user.email])
    f.close()
    pyminizip.compress(file_path, "members", response, "pass", int(1))
    return response
```

getting this error

```
ValueError at /get_csv_file/
expected arguments are compress(srcfile, prefix, zipfile, password, compress_level)
```

Answer (score 0):

The "zipfile" argument in the `pyminizip.compress` function is expecting a file path to write a zip file, howeer you've supplied a HttpResponse object, so it doesn't know what to do with it.

You'll need to temporarily write the file to disk, and then read it to be able to send it back

Comment: if i write as this, zipped_file = pyminizip.compress(file_path, "members", dist_path, "pass", int(1)), where dist_path is the temp location, how i can return it as response object